# SQL syntax error on group by having max

Tags: sql, database, grouping, aggregate-functions, sybase

I have the following query where I want to return some information notifications sent to users regarding events.  In this case I want to return only the most recent event date from the notification table.

```
select ntcf.emp_first_name, ntcf.emp_last_name, ntcf.emp_id, evt.evt_num, ntcf.ntcf_dte, ntcf.ntcf_id
from    evt_t evt, 
        ntcf_t ntcf
where 
    ntcf.ntcf_id = evt.ntcf_id and
group by evt.evt_num
having max(ntcf.evt_dte)
```

However, Sybase tells me I have "Incorrect syntax near ')'" Am I doing something wrong here regards grouping / selecting MAX? I generally don't see a syntax error and the error message isn't very helpful if it's some issue with what I'm grouping by / aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing generates the expression `max(ntcf.evt_dte)` in the query, so `HAVING` doesn't have anything to check.

The `HAVING` clause is for additional filtering of results.  It is not used for additional calculations.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. it should be written as a sub query, something like "where blah and ntcf.evt_dte = (select max(evt_dte) from blah where blah'